# Can't connect PI with WIFI Dongle by configuring the PI in two different ways

Tags: wifi

I used the Edimax wifi dongle on the Raspberry Pi, by using the `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan`, I can get a list of wireless networks, and I found my wireless network information, such as

Protocol: IEEE 802.11bgn
Mode :Master
Encryption key :on
IE: IEEE 802.11I/WPA2 version 1
Group Cipher : CCMP
Pairwise Ciphers : CCMP
Authentication suites :PSK

Then I tried two ways to change the WLAN configuration,
1. go to interfaces

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
###iface wlan0 inet manual
###wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid **MYSSID**
wpa-psk  **MYPSK**
```

then I saved the file, and reboot, check the ifconfig, still can't find the IP on WLAN0
I tried the second way.
go to interfaces

```
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

then go to wpa_supplicant.conf

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
network={
   ssid=**MYSSID**
   psk= **MYPSK**
   # Protocol type can be: RSN (for WP2) and WPA (for WPA1)
   proto=WPA
   key_mgmt=WPA-PSK 
   pairwise=CCMP
   group = CCMP
   auth_alg=OPEN
   scan_ssid=1
}
```

then save it , reboot it, ifconfig , still don't work

I can' t figure out what is wrong with it now

the WIFI dong only give blue light when I command : iwlist wlan0 scan

Comment: I see you changed wireless0 to wlan0. was that just a typing error?

Comment: yes,sorry, it is a typing error. I prefer to work on the first approach, but still don't work

Answer (score 2):

first ,check whether lsmod lists your 8192cu.ko module. If not compile it for the specific kernel version and insert it.

Apply a sudo dhclient wlan0 ( usually lack of ip address is because of the error in wpa_supplicant.conf file )  This usually fixes mine..